# Continue training a Doc2Vec model

Tags: neural-network, gensim

Gensim's [official tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) explicitly states that it is possible to continue training a (loaded) model. I'm aware that according to the documentation it is not possible to continue training a model that was loaded from the `word2vec` format. But even when one generates a model from scratch and then tries to call the `train` method, it is not possible to access the newly created labels for the `LabeledSentence` instances supplied to `train`.

```
>>> sentences = [LabeledSentence(['first', 'sentence'], ['SENT_0']), LabeledSentence(['second', 'sentence'], ['SENT_1'])]
>>> model = Doc2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
>>> print(model.vocab.keys())
dict_keys(['SENT_0', 'SENT_1', 'sentence', 'first', 'second'])
>>> sentence = LabeledSentence(['third', 'sentence'], ['SENT_2'])
>>> model.train([sentence])
>>> print(model.vocab.keys())

# At this point I would expect the key 'SENT_2' to be present in the vocabulary, but it isn't
dict_keys(['SENT_0', 'SENT_1', 'sentence', 'first', 'second'])
```

Is it at all possible to continue the training of a Doc2Vec model in Gensim with new sentences? If so, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understand is that this is not possible for any new labels. We can only continue training when the new data has the same labels as the old data. As a result, we are training or retuning the weights of the already learned vocabulary, but are not able to learn a new vocabulary.

There is a similar question for adding new labels/words/sentences during training: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/word2vec-toolkit/online$20word2vec/word2vec-toolkit/L9zoczopPUQ/_Zmy57TzxUQJ

Also, you might want to keep an eye on this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/UZDkfKwe9VI

Update: If you want to add new words to an already trained model, take a look at online word2vec here:
https://rutumulkar.com/ml-notes/word2vec/representation%20learning/2015/08/22/word2vec.html

Answer (score 2):

According to gensim documentation online/incremental training is not supported for doc2vec.

refer to https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1019

I could still add new documents to an existing doc2vec model( but some it crashes due to segmentation fault) but most similar query does not work on newly added document(so this approach seems useless).